# How to convert number value into array with separate value at array where max value of index at list will be 1

Tags: javascript, arrays, arraylist

Need some help.

I have example value 4.8 (it's a value from rating 4.8/5)

Now I need to convert it into array where array should be like this

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 0.8]
```

What do I mean? It should take value and make array with 5 elements but each of index should be not more than 1.

Other examples:

2.8 should be [1, 1, 0.8, 0 ,0]

0.5 should be [0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0]

5 should be [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

3 should be [1, 1, 1, 0, 0]

etc...

```
let number = 4.8;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Array.from()` by setting the length to 5. On each take the minimum between 0 and the max of `num - i` or 1:

```js
const convert = num => Array.from({ length: 5 }, 
  (_, i) =>  Math.max(Math.min(num - i, 1), 0)
)

console.log(convert(4.5))
console.log(convert(2.5))
console.log(convert(0.5))
console.log(convert(5))
```

And if precision is an issue, I've added a `safeSubtract` function to handle that:

```js
const safeSubtract = (n, i) => {
  const [int, dec = ''] = String(n).split('.')
  return +`${+int - i}.${dec}`
};

const convert = num => Array.from({ length: 5 }, 
  (_, i) =>  Math.max(Math.min(safeSubtract(num, i), 1), 0)
)

console.log(convert(4.8))
console.log(convert(2.8))
console.log(convert(0.8))
console.log(convert(5))
```

Answer (score 2):

**Note** I handle the rounding issue which converts 0.8 into 0.7999999999999998 in some of the other answers, at least in their first versions

```js
const conv = n => {
  let [whole, dec] = ("" + n).split("."); // split the number
  let newArr = Array
    .from({length: 5})  // create a 5 item long array
    .fill(1, 0, whole)  // fill with 1s until the whole number
    .fill(0, whole, 5); // fill with 0s for the rest
  if (dec) newArr[whole] = +("." + dec); // insert the decimals if needed
  return newArr;
}

// test:
[2.8, .5, 5, 3, 4.789].map(n => console.log(n,":",...conv(n)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could calculate each position and get the rest for the next loop.

```js
function getStars(v) {
    return Array.from({ length: 5 }, _ => Math.max(Math.min(v--, 1), 0));
}

console.log(...getStars(0.5));
console.log(...getStars(2));
console.log(...getStars(2.8)); // needs some rounding ...
```

Comment: function getStars(v) {
    return Array.from({ length: 5 }, _ => {
        var value = v && +(v > 1) || v;
        v -= value;
        return (!Number.isInteger(value))?parseFloat((value).toFixed(1)):value;
    });
}

Answer (score 0):

Get the base integer number and the decimal number. Populate the beginning indexes with 1s for however many whole numbers there are. Then, add the decimal in the next index. You may want to do some checks to make sure the number is less than 5 (your array size);

```
    let arr = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
    let number = 4.8;
    let base = Math.floor(number);
    let decimal = number - base;

    for(let i=0; i<base; i++) {
       arr[i] = 1;
    }
    arr[base] = decimal;
```

Answer (score 0):

EDITED: I handle rounding issues, now.

You can try with a `numToArray` function like the following one:

```js
function numToArray(num) {
  let intPart = Math.floor(num)
  let result = Array()
  for(let i = 0; i < intPart; i++) {
    result.push(1)
  }
  if(num > intPart) {
    result.push(Number((num - intPart).toFixed(2)))
  }
  return result
}



console.log(numToArray(2.8))
console.log(numToArray(4.5))
console.log(numToArray(0.8))
console.log(numToArray(4))
```

Comment: It's a matter of decimal numbers representation and rounding in JS: you can try to put `4.8 - 4` in a JS console (e.g. in you browser) ad you'll obtain `0.7999999999999998` :-( We can use `toFixed` function in order to avoid awful results like the one you spotted!, but we should then reconvert string to number......

Answer (score 0):

Could do something like this:

```js
let n = 3.8;
let arr = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
let i = 0;
for (; n > 0; n--) {
 arr[i] = n >= 1 ? 1 : parseFloat(n.toFixed(10)); // Fixing js float problems
 i++;
}
console.log(arr);
```